# Failed to decode JSON object in FLASK 2.0.2 with request.json and Postman

Tags: python, json, flask, post, decode

I am using Postman in order to do a POST request to my API in FLASK 2.0.2

The postman data:
[Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DUXg.png)
[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUfvQ.png)

The code that I am trying to do is:

```
app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])
app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)
app.wsgi_app = GlobalAuth(app.wsgi_app)
configure_logging(app)

api = Api(app)

class Test(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def post():
        request.on_json_loading_failed(e="a")
        data = request.json
        return make_response(data,200)

api.add_resource(Test,'/test')
```

In the middleware (GlobalAuth)

```
class GlobalAuth:
    pass
    '''
    Simple WSGI middleware
    '''

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)
        args = request.args
        body_args = request.json
```

The request.json is working but in the endpoint it is rasing an error `Failed to decode JSON object: error` if  I add to the code beforethe request.json: `request.on_json_loading_failed(e="error")`